# inverted triangle using Teradata stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata, teradatasql

I want inverted triangle using teradata sql. I have written below recursive query and getting the output. But i want to print inverted triangle using stored procedure .

with recursive atr_col(id, val)
AS
(
sel 1, cast('*' as varchar(1000)) as val
from (sel 1 as dummy) a
union all
sel tb2.id+1, trim(tb2.val)||'*'
from atr_col tb2
where tb2.id<=val)
sel val from atr_col order by id desc;

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *print inverted triangle using stored procedure*? And what are you actually trying to achieve, returning '*'s?

Comment: i want to write a procedure that will print inverted triangle in teradata

Comment: What does *print* mean, return it as an answer set? You need a dummy cursor, see https://docs.teradata.com/reader/CeAGk~BNtx~axcR0ed~5kw/JvQJaDKG9tlIvn1~6~UsCg

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be really helpful here.